# Want to read the content's between "# HCI Command" and "#---------------" in below Text using python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, findall

Following regular expression is not working:

```
re.findall("/dev[^#]+# HCI Command\nHCICommand\n\{[^\}]+\}\n# Command_Opcode = [^#]+#([^\n]+)+#---", fdata)
```

The data:

```
/dev/btpci0: 2/13/2021 22:31:58.732         Info-Log "Transport opened"
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

/dev/btpci0: 2/13/2021 22:31:59.233         Info-Log "Looking for 1 events"
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

/dev/btpci0: 2/13/2021 22:31:59.234         # HCI Command
HCICommand
{[03 0C 00]}
# Command_Opcode = 0xC03 (3075, "Reset")
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

/dev/btpci0: 2/13/2021 22:31:59.242         # HCI Event
HCIEvent
{[0E 04]: 01 03 0C 00}
# event = 0xE (14, "Command Complete")
# Num_HCI_Command_Packets = 0x1 (1)
# Command_Opcode = 0xC03 (3075, "Reset")
# Status = 0x0 (0, "Success")
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

/dev/btpci0: 2/13/2021 22:31:59.275         # HCI Command
HCICommand
{[01 0C 08]: FF 9F FB FF 07 F8 BF 3D}
# Command_Opcode = 0xC01 (3073, "Set_Event_Mask")
# Event_Mask = 0xFFFB9FFF (4294680575, "Inquiry Complete event | Inquiry Result event | Connection Complete event | Connection Request event | Disconnection Complete event | Authentication Complete event | Remote Name Request Complete event | Encryption Change event | Change Connection Link Key Complete event | Master Link Key Complete event | Read Remote Supported Features Complete event | Read Remote Version Information Complete event | QoS Setup Complete event | Hardware Error event | Flush Occurred event | Role Change event | Mode Change event | Return Link Keys event | PIN Code Request event | Link Key Request event | Link Key Notification event | Loopback Command event | Data Buffer Overflow event | Max Slots Change event | Read Clock Offset Complete event | Connection Packet Type Changed event | QoS Violation event | Page Scan Mode Change event | Page Scan Repetition Mode Change event")
# Event_Mask (63:32) = 0x3DBFF807 (1035991047, "Flow Specification Complete Event | Inquiry result With RSSI event | Read Remote Extended Features Complete event | Synchronous Connection Complete event | Synchronous Connection Changed event | Sniff Subrating event | Extended Inquiry Result event | Encryption Key Refresh Complete event | IO Capability Request event | IO Capability Response event | User Confirmation Request event | User Passkey Request event | Remote OOB Data Request event | Simple Pairing Complete event | Link Supervision Timeout Changed event | Enhanced Flush event | User Passkey Notification event | Keypress Notification event | Remote Host Supported Features Notification event | LE Meta-event")
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

/dev/btpci0: 2/13/2021 22:31:59.277         # HCI Event
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update this part `([^\n]+)+` to `(?:(?!#---).*\n)*` to prevent the catastrophic backtracking.

Also note that repeating a capture group will contain the value of the last iteration, but you want the whole part instead, which will be returned by re.findall.

To prevent overmatching, you can add a negative lookahead `(?!#---` to make sure to match lines that do not start with `#---`

Start the capture group at `(HCICommand` to capture the whole part.

```
/dev[^#]+# HCI Command\n(HCICommand\n\{[^}]+\}\n# Command_Opcode = [^#]+#(?:(?!#---).*\n)*)#---
```

The pattern matches

- `/dev[^#]+#` Match `/dev` followed by 1+ times of any char except `#` and then match `#`
- `HCI Command\n` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `HCICommand\n\{[^}]+\}\n` Match `HCICommand`, a newline and from opening till closing curly and newline
  - `# Command_Opcode = [^#]+#` Match `# Command_Opcode =`  and 1+ times any char except `#`, then match the `#`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!#---).*\n` a whole line and a newline if it does not start with `#---` *(As the `.*` will match the whole line, and the `*` is greedy, without the lookahead will will match until the last occurrence of `#---`)*
  - `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close group 1
- `#---` Match literally

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5tFx79/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/n6i2Ah)

Comment: Thanks, the solution is working. Can you please help to elaborate catastrophic backtracking? Also the following pattern ?:(?!#---). Trying to understand more on this.

Comment: @ManoharDurgaPrasadK I will add an explanation to the answer about the pattern. For catastrophic backtracking, these pages are also helpful https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html or https://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html